# How to render NotFound Component react-router-config

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new to react I would like to implement server side rendering with react router 4 I am using this package react-router-config to write plain routes But I don't why not found component is not rendering it always access the parents routes and in parent routes if user not authenticated they will redirected .Not found is not rendering as expected

[image]

Code

```
import Home from './containers/Home';
import PrivateLayout from './containers/PrivateLayout';
import NewTest from './containers/NewTest'
import TestBoard from './containers/TestBoard';
import Profile from './containers/Profile';
import NotFound from './containers/NotFound';
import PublicLayout from './containers/PublicLayout';
export default [
    {
        ...Home,
        path:'/',
        exact:true
    },
    {
        ...PublicLayout,
        routes:[
            {
                ...Profile,
                path:'/@:username',
                exact:true
            },
            {
                ...PrivateLayout,
                routes:[
                    {
                        ...TestBoard,
                        path:'/home',
                        exact:true

                    },
                    {
                        ...NewTest,
                        path:'/test/:username',
                        exact:true
                    }
                ]
            },


        ]
    },
    {
        ...NotFound,
    },
]
```

index.js

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Routes from './Routes';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { renderRoutes } from 'react-router-config';
import { BrowserRouter ,Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import reducers from './reducers';
import './index.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Map } from 'immutable';
import CONFIG from './config'

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL:CONFIG.HOST,
    withCredentials: true
});


const INITIAL_STATE = window.INITIAL_STATE || {};

Object
    .keys(INITIAL_STATE)
    .forEach(key => {
        INITIAL_STATE[key] = Map(INITIAL_STATE[key]);
    });


const store = createStore(reducers,INITIAL_STATE, applyMiddleware(reduxThunk.withExtraArgument(axiosInstance)));

window.store = store;

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
               <div>{renderRoutes(Routes)}</div>
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
    , document.getElementById('root'));
```

UPDATE #1

Why different Layout ?

I have common Header (or) Logged In Header to be showed on both profile Page and private Layout Components .To be clear Profile page will displayed even user logged out But Private Layout content will not be displayed it will be redirected

Example Import

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';


class NotFound extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <h1>Not Found</h1>
        )
    }
}

export default {
    component:NotFound
}
```

After Updating the Zarcode Answer I got an error Like this

> index.js:2177 Warning: React does not recognize the `computedMatch`
>   prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the
>   DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `computedmatch`
>   instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove
>   it from the DOM element.
>       in div (at index.js:39)
>       in Switch (at index.js:38)
>       in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
>       in BrowserRouter (at index.js:37)
>       in Provider (at index.js:36)

And HTML Render Looked Like this

[image]

UPDATE #2

I noticed wired Behaviour If I changed the notFound component inside the private routes it is working But the problem it is working for only Logged in Routes.

```
...
    {
                ...PrivateLayout,
                routes:[
                    {
                        ...TestBoard,
                        path:'/home',
                        exact:true

                    },
                    {
                        ...NewTest,
                        path:'/test/:username',
                        exact:true
                    },
                    {
                        ...NotFound,
                    },
                ]
            }
...
```

Comment: can you specify what Profile, PublicLayout, etc are composed of? I'm assuming an object like { component: Something }

Comment: Can we see how you render this configuration?

Comment: @Lokuzt  Updated the Question

Comment: @zarcode Updated the Question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you wrap routes in [`<Switch>`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch) when you render them:

```
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
       {renderRoutes(routes)}
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

**EDIT:**

You should add the path to `PublicLayout` because route without a path always match (as you can read [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/path-string)) and don't let your `NotFound` to match ever.

Comment: Updated the Question Got Some Error

Comment: Hmm,it is Kind of working But I need my Public Url Structure Like this ```http://example.com/@:username```  If I add some path to public route it will be something like this Right ```http://example.com/publicLayout/@:username```

Comment: Then you don't need `PublicLayout` in routes. If its some kind of wrapping component you can import it into its current children (Profile and PrivateLayout) and wrap their content with it...

Comment: Like High Order Component Of Course I've also Tried that But When it comes to loading data from server side Can I call High Order Component's loadData from Server Side ?

Comment: No, I didn't mean HOC, more like: `render(){ return (<PublicLayout> content of Profile </PublicLayout>) }` if you use it as a wrapper layout (based on its name), it can call loading data for your child components with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

NotFound won't ever get rendered since it'll always match PublicLayout's path first.

I'd recommend adding a namespace, for example:

```
export default [
    {
        ...Home,
        path:'/',
        exact:true
    },
    {
        ...PublicLayout,
        path: '/public', // Added
        routes:[
            {
                ...Profile,
                path:'/@:username',
                exact:true
            },
            {
                ...PrivateLayout,
                routes:[
                    {
                        ...TestBoard,
                        path:'/home',
                        exact:true

                    },
                    {
                        ...NewTest,
                        path:'/test/:username',
                        exact:true
                    }
                ]
            },

        ]
    },

    {
        ...NotFound,
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the route

```
  {
    path: '/pathanme/',
    exact: true,
    strict: true,
    check: routeService.check.auth(),
    name: 'routeName',
    component: componentName,
    cache: 0,
  }
```

Internally renderRoutes work like normal react-router

```
   <Switch {...switchProps}>
      {
        routes.map((route, i) => (
          <Route
            key={route.key || i}
            path={route.path}
            exact={route.exact}
            strict={route.strict}
            render={(props) => {
              const location = route.check && route.check(props);
              if (location) {
                props.history.push(location);
                return null;
              }
              return (
                <route.component
                  {...props}
                  {...extraProps}
                  route={route}
                />
              );
            }}
          />
        ))
      }
    </Switch>
```

this is, How render route working internally.

I have added a render prop in **< Route >** where you can right your own logic. I have passed one more property from route called **check** where I'm checking that user is loggedin or not. Accordingly I'm loading component.